# Solving PDEs by a first integral of a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Consider a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$X=a(u,v)\frac{\partial}{\partial u}+b(u,v)\frac{\partial}{\partial v}.$$
Given smooth functions $p(u,v), q(u,v)$, how do we solve
$$Xf+pf=q$$
for $f(u,v)$ from a geometric viewpoint? I found something in the internet. If $p$ and $q$ are identically zero, then the job is done by examining a first integral of $X$. However, this is not the case. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by a geometric viewpoint? Can't you just use the method of characteristics?

Comment: Indeed, the method of characteristics does work, but I was asked to formulate another approach, concerning the vector field, to this problem.

Comment: John Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* contains a small section on geometric descriptions of precisely these sorts of first order PDEs. See [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-9982-5_9.pdf) (pg.239)

Comment: @Kajelad Thank you. This is gonna help.